# Sistema de Login¿Algún consejo?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, revisión-de-código

Mis dudas principales son:
¿Puedo sacar todas las consultas SQL de esta clase y llevarlas a "otro sitio"(clase, XML, param, etc...?
¿Todos esos If's, son necesarios o se podrían sustituir por algo "mejor"?

## Login()

```
Public Shared Function LoginMetodo(CadenaConexion As String, Usuario As String, Contraseña As String, ByRef LabelIntentos As String) As Usuario

    Dim contraseñaDecrypted As String = DecryptPassword(CadenaConexion, Usuario, Contraseña)

    Dim miUsuario As Usuario
    Dim parUsuario As New SqlParameter("@usuario", Usuario)
    Dim parContraseña As New SqlParameter("@contrasena", contraseñaDecrypted)
    LabelIntentos = ""
    Dim consulta As String = "select id, usuario, estado, intentos from Usuarios where usuario = @usuario"
    Dim consultaRestablecerIntentos As String = "update Usuarios set intentos = 5, estado = 1 where usuario = @usuario"
    Dim consultaRestarIntentos As String = "update Usuarios set intentos = intentos -1 where usuario = @usuario; select intentos from usuarios where usuario = @usuario"
    Dim consultaCancelarEstado As String = "update Usuarios set intentos = 0, estado = 0 where usuario = @usuario"
    Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consulta, parUsuario)

    Try
        If Not (contraseñaDecrypted.Equals("1")) Then 'Entra aquí si el usuario existe y la contraseña es correcta'
            If (objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2) > 0 And objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3) > 0) Then
                miUsuario = New Usuario(objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0))
                LabelIntentos = "Conectando..."
                SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consultaRestablecerIntentos, parUsuario)
            Else
                LabelIntentos = "Usuario bloqueado." & vbCr & "Contacte con el administrador para activar la cuenta"
                SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consultaCancelarEstado, parUsuario)
            End If


        ElseIf (objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3) > 0) Then 'resta un intento al usuario y actualiza la label de intentos restantes'
            LabelIntentos = "Intentos restantes: " & SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consultaRestarIntentos,
                                                                              parUsuario).Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString

        Else
            LabelIntentos = "Usuario bloqueado." & vbCr & "Contacte con el administrador para activar la cuenta"
            SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consultaCancelarEstado, parUsuario) 'el usuario queda desactivado'
        End If
        Return miUsuario
    Catch ice As InvalidCastException
        MsgBox("InvalidCastException")
        Throw ice
    Catch ioore As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MsgBox("IndexOutOfRangeException")
        Throw ioore
    Catch drie As DeletedRowInaccessibleException
        MsgBox("DeletedRowInaccessibleException")
        Throw drie
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.StackTrace)
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

## Desencriptar contraseña()

```
Private Shared Function DecryptPassword(CadenaConexion As String, Usuario As String, Contraseña As String) As String
    Dim contraseñaDecrypted As String
    Dim parUsuario As New SqlParameter("@usuario", Usuario)
    Dim consulta As String = "DECLARE @PassphraseEnteredByUser varchar(128);  
                            SET @PassphraseEnteredByUser = N'Frase super secreta que la CIA esta buscando!';
                            SELECT usuario, Contrasena_EncryptedbyPassphrase, 
                            CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByPassphrase(@PassphraseEnteredByUser, Contrasena_EncryptedbyPassphrase, 1,
                            CONVERT(varbinary, usuario))) AS 'pass' FROM Usuarios where usuario = @usuario"
    Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consulta, parUsuario)
    If (Contraseña.Equals(objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString())) Then
        contraseñaDecrypted = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()
    ElseIf (Usuario.Equals(objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString())) Then
        contraseñaDecrypted = "1"
    End If
    Return contraseñaDecrypted
```

Comment: No entiendo por qué la pregunta es demasiado amplia. Hay dos preguntas muy concisas y acompañadas de lo que OP necesita. ¿Alguna explicación alguien de quien votó a cerrar?

Comment: @Luiggi: Disculpa por no haberle dejado un comentario a OP. Esa es usualmente mi meta, pero no lo hize esta vez. Aparte de las 2 preguntas que mencionas, las preguntas eran *¿Algún consejo?* (el título), y *¿Es posible mejorar mi código?* (que estaba allí antes de la última edición). Esas son preguntas muy amplias. Es cierto que también formuló las 2 preguntas hasta cierto grado menos específicas (discutible), pero en conjunto lo veía demasiado como que simplemente se estaba pidiendo un "code review" general. En fin, voy a votar para reabrir ya que la pregunta se mejoró un poco.

Comment: @sstan Las preguntas de revisión de código son bienvenidas :) Mirar [aqui](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/164/7242)

Comment: Claro que puedes llevar toda las consultas a tu base de datos a una clase encargada de crear la conexión a esta y devolver los resultados que tu necesitas! Como estas trabajando? MVC? en n-capas?

Comment: @Miquel: Gracias por la referencia. Aunque me parece confuso que se acepten revisiones de código, pero que a la vez no se acepten preguntas muy amplias. En general todas las revisiones de código resultan en exactamente la descripción asociada a *muy amplio*: *Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos.* ¿Será que se necesita un ajuste a la definición de lo que es una pregunta *muy amplia*?

Comment: @sstan una revisión de código puedes ser específica siempre y cuándo vaya acompañada del detalle necesario del escenario y un código que no sea muy extenso. Eso no quita que puedan ser cerradas por otros motivos =P.

Comment: @sioesi estoy trabajando en asp.net y vb.net. Y respecto a lo de las consultas, me refiero a esto: `Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, Clase-que-almacena-las-consultas.consultaNuevoUsuario`  Por otro lado, soy nuevo en StackOverflow, y aunque me he intentado leer la normativa y esas cosas, aún no me aclaro del todo. Un saludo y gracias por todo